# How does subtracting X.begin() return the index of an iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Having trouble understanding the below code:

```
int data[5] = { 1, 5, 2, 4, 3 }; 
 vector<int> X(data, data+5); 
 int v1 = *max_element(X.begin(), X.end()); // Returns value of max element in vector 
 int i1 = min_element(X.begin(), X.end()) – X.begin(); // Returns index of min element in vector
```

Not really sure how subtracting the iterator returned by X.begin returns the index of the max/min element?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `- X.begin()` ?

Comment: What's unclear about that? (The typo Paul spotted aside.)

Comment: Iterator subtraction works just like pointer subtraction. [There are a number of useful operations you can perform on iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) (and pointers). (I'm simplifying a little, as there are different types of iterators, but `vector`'s iterators are random access iterators so I'm focusing on those types of iterators in this comment).

Comment: Mind the typo.

I am just a bit confused how it returns an index from subtracting the iterator at the beginning of a container?

How exactly does the returned iterator from min_element() call minus the iterator at the beginning of the vector return an index specifically?

Comment: There's no magic, the iterator was simply designed to support this subtraction operator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::vector<T>::iterator` satisfies the [RandomAccessIterator concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), which means that it has an `operator-` that allows you to subtract two iterators and obtain a `std::vector<T>::iterator::difference_type` that indicates the distance between the two iterators.

An under-the-hood implementation for `std::vector<T>::iterator` could in fact be made using pointers as iterators, in which case the subtraction operator would just be doing pointer arithmetic. There's no *requirement* for the iterator to be implemented using pointers, but it's a potential design.

Other containers' iterators may not have this capability. For instance, `std::set<T>::iterator` only satisfies the [BidirectionalIterator concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), which specifies a less-rich set of functionality than the RandomAccessIterator concept.