# meaning of -vec.rbegin in my code for binary search?

Tags: c++, search, vector, binary, c++14

```
 ans+=lower_bound(vec.rbegin(),vec.rend(),0)-vec.rbegin();
```

Although its working i am not able to understand -vec.rbegin in this line
here is function

```
 int countNegatives(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
        int ans =0;
        for(auto& vec:grid)
            ans+=lower_bound(vec.rbegin(),vec.rend(),0)-vec.rbegin();
        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) returns an iterator. And vector iterators can be subtracted to get the "difference" (in number of vector elements) between them. This is what's happening here, the code is getting the difference between what `std::lower_bound` is returning and the `rbegin` iterator of the vector `vec`.

Comment: It'd been clearer if it had used [`std::distance(vec.rbegin(), lower_bound(vec.rbegin(),vec.rend(),0))`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does subtracting X.begin() return the index of an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919315/how-does-subtracting-x-begin-return-the-index-of-an-iterator)